# Add an incrementing ID property to each object in array after it has been submitted

Tags: node.js, arrays, express, javascript-objects, fs

I am trying to add a unique ID property to each object in an array after it has been submitted from an input & text area. When I console.log the array as I add more entries it looks like so:

```
[{"title":"hello","text":"sir"}]
```

I have two const variables I'm using currently. The contents of the note array get written in to a db.json file.

```
const notes = []; 
const newID = 0;
```

This is an express js program and below is the function I have to write the input data to the appropriate file. I would like to add an ID for each entry preferably in this function.

```
app.post("/api/notes", (req, res) => {
    let newNote = req.body;
    notes.push(newNote)
    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, 'db/db.json'), JSON.stringify(notes), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    res.end();
});
```

I've tried to map the new property unsuccessfully I've also tried a forEach to run through the array to add the id++.

Please let me know if there is any pertinent information I am missing here. Thanks in advance for any help/feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the forEach and the working code is below.

```
app.post("/api/notes", (req, res) => {
    let newNote = req.body;
    notes.push(newNote)
    notes.forEach((note, index) => {
        note.id = index + 1;
    });    
    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, 'db/db.json'), JSON.stringify(notes), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    res.end();
});
```