# How to add a unique id to an array in one loop instead of two?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Getting data from graphql, example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    items: [
      {
        link: '/monday',
        name: 'Monday',
      },
      {
        link: '/tuesday',
        name: 'Tuesday',
      },
      {
        link: '/wednesday',
        name: 'Wednesday',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    items: [
      {
        link: '/january',
        name: 'January',
      },
      {
        link: '/february',
        name: 'February',
      },
      {
        link: '/march',
        name: 'March',
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I'm trying to build a new object and also add a unique `id` but it takes me two loops to accomplish (also includes expected output):

```js
  const data = [
    {
      items: [
        {
          link: '/monday',
          name: 'Monday',
        },
        {
          link: '/tuesday',
          name: 'Tuesday',
        },
        {
          link: '/wednesday',
          name: 'Wednesday',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      items: [
        {
          link: '/january',
          name: 'January',
        },
        {
          link: '/february',
          name: 'February',
        },
        {
          link: '/march',
          name: 'March',
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
  
  let itemsObj = []
  let merge = []

  data.forEach(section => {
    section.items.forEach((item, i) => {
      return (itemsObj = [...itemsObj, item])
    })
  })

  itemsObj.map((item, i) => {
    item.id = i
    return merge.push(item)
  })
  
  console.log(itemsObj)
```

Code that correctly builds what I need but takes a `foreach` and `map`:

```js
data.forEach(section => {
  section.items.forEach((item, i) => {
    return (itemsObj = [...itemsObj, item])
  })
})

itemsObj.map((item, i) => {
  item.id = i
  return merge.push(item)
})
```

When I try to add an incremented `id` in one loop it starts over, example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    items: [
      {
        link: '/monday',
        name: 'Monday',
      },
      {
        link: '/tuesday',
        name: 'Tuesday',
      },
      {
        link: '/wednesday',
        name: 'Wednesday',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    items: [
      {
        link: '/january',
        name: 'January',
      },
      {
        link: '/february',
        name: 'February',
      },
      {
        link: '/march',
        name: 'March',
      },
    ],
  },
]

 let itemsObj = []

  data.forEach(section => {
    section.items.forEach((item, i) => {
      item.id = i
      return (itemsObj = [...itemsObj, item])
    })
  })
  
  console.log(itemsObj)
```

Code trying to add the `id` and build the object in one loop that causes the `id` to start over:

```js
let itemsObj = []

data.forEach(section => {
  section.items.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.id = i
    return (itemsObj = [...itemsObj, item])
  })
})

console.log(itemsObj)
```

Per [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67860966/1952287) same issue occurs with an `id` that isn't unique:

```js
data.flatMap(dataObj => {
  return dataObj.items.map((item, i) => {
    return { i, ...item }
  })
})
```

Expected output example to clarify comment:

```js
[
  {
    "link": "/monday",
    "name": "Monday",
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "link": "/tuesday",
    "name": "Tuesday",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "link": "/wednesday",
    "name": "Wednesday",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "link": "/january",
    "name": "January",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "link": "/february",
    "name": "February",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "link": "/march",
    "name": "March",
    "id": 5
  }
]
```

Research:

- [Add id to array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023291/add-id-to-array-of-objects)
- [Add an incrementing ID property to each object in array after it has been submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926005/add-an-incrementing-id-property-to-each-object-in-array-after-it-has-been-submit)
- [Nodejs how to put multiple id's into an if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65027051/nodejs-how-to-put-multiple-ids-into-an-if)
- [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Is there a way to an `id` in one loop instead of using a `foreach` and `map`?

Comment: What’s your expected output?

Comment: @decpk the above ran example where there is a `foreach` and `map` loop?

Comment: What do you mean by one loop as in the second code block you are still using the nested loops.

Comment: edited question with code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a variable outside of [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and increment after it gets added to end result.

You can even make it a one-liner if you'd like

```
const result = data.flatMap(({ items }) =>  items.map((item) => ({ i: start++, ...item })));
```

**1) With flatMap**

```js
const data = [
  {
    items: [
      {
        link: "/monday",
        name: "Monday",
      },
      {
        link: "/tuesday",
        name: "Tuesday",
      },
      {
        link: "/wednesday",
        name: "Wednesday",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    items: [
      {
        link: "/january",
        name: "January",
      },
      {
        link: "/february",
        name: "February",
      },
      {
        link: "/march",
        name: "March",
      },
    ],
  },
];

let start = 0;
const result = data.flatMap(({ items }) => {
  return items.map((item) => {
    return { i: start++, ...item };
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**2) With reduce**

```js
const data = [
  {
    items: [
      {
        link: "/monday",
        name: "Monday",
      },
      {
        link: "/tuesday",
        name: "Tuesday",
      },
      {
        link: "/wednesday",
        name: "Wednesday",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    items: [
      {
        link: "/january",
        name: "January",
      },
      {
        link: "/february",
        name: "February",
      },
      {
        link: "/march",
        name: "March",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, { items }, index) => {
  return [
    ...acc,
    ...items.map((o, i) => ({ i: acc.length * index + i, ...o })),
  ];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks never used `flatmap` so learned something new.

Comment: For performance which should be used, `reduce` or `flatmap`?

Comment: There is no much difference in performance, You can use anyone. It just came in my mind so I shared it, so that It can help you to understand better...

Comment: It is the unique value that you should take away from my answer i.e `i: acc.length * index + i`

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ - Note to the OP.  This is still multiple loops - it's just now a little more hidden.  There is no way to iterate an array of objects each with their own array without multiple loops.

Answer (score 1):

Try [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```
let index = 0
data.flatMap(dataObj => {
  return dataObj.items.map((item) => {
    return { i: index++, ...item }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let itemsObj = []
let index = 0;

data.forEach(section => {
  section.items.forEach((item) => {
    item.id = index;
    index++;
    return (itemsObj = [...itemsObj, item])
  })
})

console.log(itemsObj)
```